# Proportial size of html components while the browser is being resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a page, where I am displaying some html components (surprisingly :P).

The requirement is that the size of all these html components change according to how the browser window is being re-sized or how the client side resolution is.

For example, If have reduced the size of my browser window to half, how do I get the components to reduce to half, automatically.

Any pointers towards this would be helpful.

**EDIT : 
The need is for the components to remain in the same left to right order i.e. introduce horizontal scroll bar if needed.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this as easily as possible without JavaScript.  In your css make sure the width and height attributes of anything you want to re-size are in percentages and not in pixels.  Additionally if you need a child component re-size make that a percentage as well.

**For example**

**If this is your html**

*Where the container div is the html component you want to auto resize*

```
<div class="container">

    <h1> some heading</h1>
    <p>some paragraph text</p>

    <div class="childContainer">
        <p>some more text</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

*do this in your css*

```
.container
{
    width: 80%;
}

.someChildContainer
{
   width: 50%;
}
```

*not this*

```
.container
{
     width: 800px;
}
```

By using the percentage in this example, say for instance your total browser width is initially 1000px;  The container class div will display at 800px and the childContainer class will be 400px.  If the user shrinks the browser to a width of 500px, the container class will shrink to 400px and the childContainer will shrink to 200px;

In other words the percentage width of any child container is based on the current with a parent container.  If there is no parent container the percentage width is relative to the html body tag which is most cases is the width of the entire browser window.

**Here is the markup based on your sample**

```
    <html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    .alignLeft{ 
            float:left;
        }

    .container
    {
        width: 80%; 
        background-color:#ccc;
        float: left;
    }

    .fixedContainer
    {
        width: 900px;
        float: left;
        background-color:#aaa;

    }

    table
    {
       width: 300px;
       float: left;

    }
</style>

<div class="container">

<div class="fixedContainer">

<table class="searchCriteria alignLeft" cellpadding="1%"> 

 <tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalRefNum">Proposal Id :</label></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="proposalRefNum" onchange="removeSearchResults()" class="searchControl" value="" id="proposalRefNum" title="Type the Proposal RefNum you are looking for"></td> 
 </tr> 

  <tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalName">Name :</label></td> 
 <td><input type="text" name="Proposal Name" onchange="removeSearchResults()" value="" id="proposalName" class="searchControl" title="Type the Proposal description you are looking for"></td> 
 </tr> 

 <tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalDescription">Description :</label></td> 
 <td><textarea rows="2" name="Proposal description" onchange="removeSearchResults()" id="proposalDescription" class="searchControl" title="Type the Proposal description you are looking for"></textarea></td> 
 </tr> 

 <tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalApplication">Application :</label></td> 
 <td><select class="searchControl" name="application" id="proposalApplication" onchange="removeSearchResults()" title="Select the application for which you are searching the proposals">
    <option value="_ANY" selected="selected">ANY</option>
</select></td>
 </tr> 

</table>


<table class="searchCriteria alignLeft" cellpadding="10px"> 

 <tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalReleaseCandidateRefNum">Release Candidate Id :</label></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="releaseCandidateRefNum" onchange="removeSearchResults()" class="searchControl"value="" id="proposalReleaseCandidateRefNum" title="Type the release Candidate RefNum you are looking for"></td> 
 </tr> 

<tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalCreator">Creator :</label></td> 
 <td><input type="text" name="Proposal creator" onchange="removeSearchResults()"value="" id="proposalCreator" class="searchControl" title="Creator of the proposals you are looking for"></td> 
 </tr> 

 <tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalOwner">Owner :</label></td> 
 <td><input type="text" name="Proposal Owner" onchange="removeSearchResults()"value="" id="proposalOwner" class="searchControl" title="Owner of the proposals you are looking for"></td> 
 </tr> 

 <tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalLastUpdatedBy">LastUpdatedBy :</label></td> 
 <td><input type="text" name="Proposal Last Updated By" onchange="removeSearchResults()"value="" id="proposalLastUpdatedBy" class="searchControl" title="Users who last updated the proposals you are looking for"></td> 
 </tr> 

<tr> 
 <td><label for="proposalStatus" >Status:</label></td> 
 <td><select class="searchControl" onchange="removeSearchResults()" name="status" id="proposalStatus" title="Status of the proposals you are looking for">
     <option value="_ANY" selected="selected">ANY</option>
</select></td>
 </tr>
</table> 

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added my sample html here - http://jsfiddle.net/sKY7d/ . How do I implement it here, I have not explicitly set the width for any component here.

Comment: @kshitij  Put a wrapper div around you table and set that divs width to a percentage I have put a full sample based on your sample into my original answer

Comment: @kshitij also you would be wise to replace your tabular layout with a div based layout in order to get cleaner markup and more predictable behavior.  Tables should usually be reserved for content that is actually tabular data such as part of a spreadsheet, statistics, etc

Comment: The sample put in is not handling the resizes gracefully. It brings the second table below the first one, while I need them to come side by side even if it means introducing a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @kshitij Okay I've changed the code in the original post to reflect what it sounds like you need.  I also added a background color to the various containers simply to help illustrate exactly what is going on.  Note you can remove the float attributes that I included I simply added them so that the background colors would show up properly without me having to introduce a height variable, they can be removed in your production setting.

Answer (score 1):

You'll hear this often around here: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). There is a [resize event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) to which you can attach a function to resize all of your components, e.g.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //resize the components.
});
```

As @pat8719 says, to have the heights and widths scale you can just set them as percentages in your CSS, this would only be useful if you wanted to change the font/border size at some thresholds or have something fancy like collapsing components when the screen size is too small.

Comment: Also if you want to get more fancy/complicated with how your components re-size you will want to use JavaScript  as @nwellcome suggests with jQuery usually being an excellent library